# Creating a custom Source for Sitecore Template

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am very new to Sitecore, and have to customize a Template for a MultiLine Entry to have different source (List of Items) depending on the Role of the Logged-In Admin. For example the site can have multiple different Admins and each one can add/remove data for a of the page section, so

The content for MultiList of Website-1 (Edited by Admin-1) will be different from Website-2(Edited by Admin-2). So the data for Admin-1 and Admin-2 is at the following locations:

```
Admin-1: sitecore/content/Data/Features/Admin-1
Admin-2: sitecore/content/Data/Features/Admin-2
```

Now for the Source part of the Template, I can enter the path for the data: ex-`/sitecore/content/Data/Features/` and that will include all of the Items in that folder including both subfolders of "Admin-1" and "Admin-2", but what I really want is when the Admin-1 logs I want the list to be populated only with "Admin-1" content, and vice versa. Is that even possible? I am not sure what to do about that.

Comment: You say Website-1 and Website-2, and then Admin-1 and Admin-2 and also talk about each admin having access to different data for the same item. Is this a multisite implementation within Sitecore? Should Admin-1 only have access to Website-1 and Admin-2 only have access to Website-2? If so then this is easy to implement, you need to change your data structure slightly though.

Comment: Yes, Basically "MasterAdmin" (3rd user) should have the chance to modify both data, but "Admin-1" will ONLY change "Website-1" data and same thing with "Admin-2" and "Website-2". How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your question was a little ambiguous hence the reason I asked the question.

your data structure is currently a little incorrect in my opinion. I would set it up as follows:

-sitecore

--content

---common (shared between both sites)

---site-1

----home

----settings

----data

---site-2

----home

----settings

----data

Now in your template set the datasource as:

```
query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Site']/data/features/*
```

This will restrict the options for your multilist to only items in the data folder of the current site. Obviously change @@templatename to whatever yours is.

As for the permissions, you should create 2 roles, Admin-1 and Admin-2. For both roles break the inheritance on /sitecore/content node and then give Admin-1 read/write/create/delete access on /sitecore/content/site-1 and Admin-2 the same on Site-2. Make sure you do this for roles. Then add the necessary users to those roles. If a specific user needs access to both sites then add them to both roles. Use /Security Tools/Security Editor.

I would not call the roles "admin" since that can lead to confusion between the Sitecore Admin setting. Instead, I would call it "Site1ContentEditer" and "Site2ContentEditer". If you introduce workflow this gives you the opportunity to follow the naming convention, e.g. Site1ContentApprover, Site1ContentPublisher etc.

I'm a little rushed right now, but let me know if you need more info.

EDIT: This should give you more info on multisite implementation: [Building multisite solutions in Sitecore](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/10/how-to-multisite-in-sitecore.aspx)

Comment: I see your point.  I also like your solution better than my solution because it is setup to automatically handle the creation of new users and new sites since you're using a relative query.  I've marked my answer to be deleted.

Comment: No problem. For the benefit of others, why you should break inheritance rather than deny permission: http://theclientview.net/2011/04/sitecore-recommended-practices-part-3-security-roles-and-users/